# how to use google font (roboto) to customize and make a link to import to html file?

Tags: html, css

maybe google font roboto made a change to their website so I had a problem when using their product to customize font and make a link to embed to my html file.

I studied and as my tutorial, they said that when I use this website

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

I can see at the corner the word "select this font", then click to it.

It will show me the table family selected.

At this table, I can customize many thing what I want such as languages, font for example.

Then it will show me the embed link then I only copy this embed link to the html file, it will work.

But in the new roboto page, there is no "select this font" button or link ?

So how can I customize or make the link to embed to my html file ?

Could you please give me some update tutorial to use this roboto ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is "select this style" with + button for each variation of the font. Select all the variations you want and then you'll get the link on the panel where selected families are stored.

Answer (score 1):

It's all still there! Just moved around!

[image: Google Fonts Layout Changed]

Comment: thank you, your answer is so great, I have just only refer and use and now it worked.